# Pandas: Replace every value in every column matching a pattern with a value from another column in that row

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with 1000 columns.  I want to replace every -9 value in every column with that row's df['a'] value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [6, -9, 8, np.nan, -9], 'c': [-9, 19, -9, -9, -9]})
```

What I want is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [6, 2, 8, np.nan, 5], 'c': [1, 19, 3, 4, 5]})
```

I have tried

```
df.replace(-9, df['a'], inplace = True)
```

And

```
df.replace(-9, np.nan, inplace = True)
df.fillna(df.a, inplace = True)
```

But they don't change the df.

My solution right now is to use a for loop:

```
df.replace(-9, np.nan, inplace = True)
col_list = list(df)
for i in col_list:
   df[i].fillna(df['a'], inplace = True)
```

This solution works, but it also replaces any np.nan values.  Any ideas as to how I can replace just the -9 values without first converting it into np.nan?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.mask(df == -9, df['a'], axis=0)
print (df)
   a    b   c
0  1  6.0   1
1  2  2.0  19
2  3  8.0   3
3  4  NaN   4
4  5  5.0   5
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df == -9, df['a'].values[:, None], df), columns=df.columns)
print (df)
     a    b     c
0  1.0  6.0   1.0
1  2.0  2.0  19.0
2  3.0  8.0   3.0
3  4.0  NaN   4.0
4  5.0  5.0   5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do something like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_tar = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [6, 2, 8, np.nan, 5], 'c': [1, 19, 3, 4, 5]})


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [6, -9, 8, np.nan, -9], 'c': [-9, 19, -9, -9, -9]})
df.loc[df['b']==-9,'b']=df.loc[df['b']==-9,'a']
df.loc[df['c']==-9,'c']=df.loc[df['c']==-9,'a']
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your solution works with the example data, but I have 1000 column names (b, c, d,e,....).  Jezrael's solution is exactly what I am looking for.